# How to create a file with contents based on files in a directory

Tags: excel, vba

I have an existing xls file which creates a CONTENTS file based on the files in a directory. For example, if a directory contains file.pdf and file.txt, it will create a file with contents

```
file.pdf
file.txt
```

with each file separated by a line break.

What I would like to do is that I want the contents to contain

```
file.pdf    bundle:ORIGINAL
file.txt    bundle:TEXT
```

`file.pdf` and `bundle:ORIGINAL` is separated by a `tab` character. The directory will contain these 2 filetypes, 1 pdf and 1 text file. So basically, what I want is that for every pdf file, it should be followed by `bundle:ORIGINAL` text while if its a text file, it should be followed by `bundle:TEXT`.

The original code is below:

```
For i = 2 To lRows
If Trim(Cells(i, 1).Value) = "" Then Exit For

' create the CONTENTS file

FileList = GetFileList(oDirectory & "\" & Trim(Cells(i, lCols).Value) & "\")
cFileNum = FreeFile
ContentsPath = oDirectory & "\" & Trim(Cells(i, lCols).Value) & "\" & "contents"
Open ContentsPath For Output As #cFileNum
For k = 1 To UBound(FileList)
If (FileList(k) <> "contents" And FileList(k) <> "dublin_core.xml") Then
    Print #cFileNum, FileList(k)
    End If
    Next k
Close #cFileNum
```

**EDIT**

This is the Function GetFileList

```
Function GetFileList(FileSpec As String) As Variant
'   Returns an array of filenames that match FileSpec
'   If no matching files are found, it returns False

Dim FileArray() As Variant
Dim FileCount As Integer
Dim FileName As String

On Error GoTo NoFilesFound

FileCount = 0
FileName = Dir(FileSpec)
If FileName = "" Then GoTo NoFilesFound

'   Loop until no more matching files are found
Do While FileName <> ""
    FileCount = FileCount + 1
    ReDim Preserve FileArray(1 To FileCount)
    FileArray(FileCount) = FileName
    FileName = Dir()
Loop
GetFileList = FileArray
Exit Function

'   Error handler
NoFilesFound:
GetFileList = False
End Function
```

Please note that I am obviously not the author of this code, I just downloaded this excel file (the site no longer exists) a long time ago and I just need to tweak this for my own use.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
'...
If (FileList(k) <> "contents" And FileList(k) <> "dublin_core.xml") Then
    Print #cFileNum, FileList(k) & vbTab & GetType(Cstr(FileList(k)))
End If
'...
```

Function:

```
Function GetType(fName as string)
    Dim rv As String
    Select Case Right(Ucase(fName),3)
        Case "TXT": rv = "bundle:TEXT"
        Case "PDF": rv = "bundle:ORIGINAL"
    End Select
    GetType = rv
End Function
```

Comment: When I run the macro, I received this error: `Compile error: ByRef argument type mismatch`. Please advice how to resolve this. Many thanks.

Comment: See my edit  -added `Cstr()` around `FileList(k)`.  The function expects a String-typed argument (or you could switch the argument type to variant).